# Get telegram profile photo with telethon

Tags: react-native, telegram, telethon

I am trying create avatar component for profile user / channel / group, I received data of photo as below but how to display in app

CONSTRUCTOR_ID:3973537164
SUBCLASS_OF_ID:3325267837
photoId:6231075280034835000
photoSmall:
CONSTRUCTOR_ID:3162490573
SUBCLASS_OF_ID:2432133155
volumeId:500013300251
localId:72397
photoBig
CONSTRUCTOR_ID:3162490573
SUBCLASS_OF_ID:2432133155
volumeId:500013300251
localId:72399
dcId:5

Comment: You did not ask question

Comment: Yes, I want to show photo getting from telegram in my app

Comment: @ASP.NETMVC and what are you looking for? What did you tried already? Read [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) section on StackOverlow